# Мне нужна функция,чтобы считать числа из файла c текстом и записать их в массив[][]

Tags: java

Мне нужна функция,чтобы считать числа из файла  с таким  содержанием числа и записать их в массив[][] :

```
kategorie\grupy,grupaA,grupaB
kategoria1,100,200
kategoria2,300,400
```

Т.е. на выходе хочу иметь массив состоящий из :

```
array[0][0]=100;
..
array[1][1]=40;
```

---

Функция должна быть универсальна,так чтобы скажем смогла обработать следующий текст:

```
kategorie\grupy,grupaA,grupaB,grupaC
kategoria1,100,200,300
kategoria2,300,400,500
kategoria3,60,10,12
```

Я пробовал использовать replaceAll , но он в результати я получал массив с цифрами из которых состоят выше указанные числа

```
  int q = 0;
    String correctText = "";
    String symbols[];
    int nums[];

    public void readFile() {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D://z4data1.csv"))) {
            String textFromFile;
            while ((textFromFile = br.readLine()) != null) {
                correctText = textFromFile;
                if (correctText != null) {
                    System.out.println(correctText);
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Что пробовали делать? Что не получается? Приведите примеры кода.

Comment: Код добавил.Надеюсь на помощь

Comment: Если вам нужен именно массив массивов `массив[ ][ ]` без использования коллекций, то для его объявления нужно знать количество строк: `int[ ][ ] jaggedArr = new int[20][ ];`, поэтому первым проходом нужно получить количество строк в файле. А дальше уже заполнять другими массивами с числами: `jaggedArr[0] = new int[] {1, 2};`.

Comment: Вторые массивы вы можете получить, сделав [Split на строку](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) по запятой и приведя нужные части полученного массива в числа.